# Powershell Explicitly grabbing properties from sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I keep getting this error messeage when I try look at a ViewCollection from a list

> format-default : The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], CollectionNotInitializedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand

I believe my `$list.views`  object is not being initialized. I have tried the following

```
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.Load($list.views)
$ctx.Load($list, 'Views')     <-- incorrect syntax  and other variations
```

I know I need a SP.ClientObject  to load into the context before running my ExecuteQuery  but the only examples I see are c# code which uses lambda Expressions  to load in properties explicitly but I am unaware of how to do the same thing in powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$ClientContext.Load($list.Views)`syntax  in PowerShell to load Views collection, for example:

```
$list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
$Context.Load($list)
$Context.Load($list.Views)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
if ($list.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated('Views') -eq $true)
{
   Write-Host "Views collection has been loaded"
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this out?   From what I saw online  you practically had to write C# code inside of powershell.   I could have Sworn I have tried

    `$Context.Load($list.Views)`

before and it still didn't load it.

Comment: Yep, the specified code works for me just fine, there is no need to inject c# code

Comment: cool Ill give it a try later today when I get off of work

Comment: of course it works, it's Vadim's code, +1